# The process "mingw32-make.exe" crashed Error

Tags: c++, windows, qt, mingw, qt-quick

I have downloaded qt-windows-opensource-5.0.1-mingw47_32-x86-offline.exe and installed on my system, after that i launched QT Creator and tried to run a QML based example (shipped example is "QtQuick Examples - MouseArea" which tried, and below problem comes with any example i try to run) which was supplied with along with the whole package.

When i try to run the project i get below log...

```
13:00:20: Running steps for project mousearea...
13:00:20: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
13:00:20: Starting: "mingw32-make.exe" 
qtcreator_ctrlc_stub: Command line failed: mingw32-make.exe
13:00:20: The process "mingw32-make.exe" crashed.
Error while building/deploying project mousearea (kit: Desktop Qt 5.0.1 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step 'Make'
```

Comment: The problem was resolved later on, I installed qt-windows-opensource-5.0.1-mingw47_32-x86-offline.exe on 64bit system and that's why mingw32-make.exe crashed, downloading appropriate QT for 64bit system solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved later on, I installed qt-windows-opensource-5.0.1-mingw47_32-x86-offline.exe on 64bit system and that's why mingw32-make.exe crashed, downloading appropriate QT for 64bit system solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have mingw47_32 installed? The Qt you download needs the very same compiler the Qt libraries where compiled with, and that is the one that appears in the name of the download.

So my guess is that you're compiling with some other mingw which is not version 4.7 / 32 bits. Download that version, point Qt to it in Tools >> Options >> Kits. Rebuild then.